# Finding the bias of an estimator for a beta distribution based on method of moments?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is a sample from a beta distribution with the PDF as
$f(x) = (\theta + 1)x^\theta, 0 < x < 1, \theta > -1$. With the method of moments, I can derive that

$$\bar{X} = \mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{\theta + 1}{\theta + 2},$$

so an estimator for $\theta$ is

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{1 - \bar{X}} - 2.$$

But I got stuck when I tried to compute the expectation of $\hat{\theta}$. I don't know how to derive the distribution of $\bar{X}$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What you are really saying is that estimating $\mathbb{E}[X]$ using the average of the $X_i$'s, you get the formula above. In other words,
$$
\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{1- \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k} - 2
 = \frac{n}{n- \sum_{k=1}^n X_k} - 2,
$$
which is a random variable, depending on the particular values of the $X_k$'s. But you know the distribution of the $X_K$'s, can you now compute the expected value of $\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: My idea was to find the distribution for $\sum_{n=1}^k X_k$ with moment generating function, then the distribution for $\frac{n}{n-\sum_{n=1}^k X_k}$. But the MGF seemed to be very complicated. Could you give me more hints?

Comment: @Yujian MGF sounds like a good idea, here is Wolfram Alpha [computing the MGF](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bt*x%5D*x%5Ea%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) for one of the $X_k$'s.